# Url Amigável/Otimizada não abre

Tags: php, apache, url, seo, url-amigável

Estou otimizando as URLs de um site e tive um certo problema. Algumas páginas não abrem depois de receber a otimização, na verdade a página é encontrada e inserida no caminho, mas o conteúdo da página fica o mesmo.

Em algumas fui modificando/removendo algumas palavras e foi resolvendo.

Alguém sabe me dizer o que pode ser?

Comment: felups você tem algum exemplo de código que esta utilizando?

Comment: Flávio, segue um exemplo de url que não abre http://oprojetoweb.com.br/provas/security-condominios-programado/cancela-catraca-magnetic-autocontrol-mbe30-mbe35-mbe50-slim-drive. Acesse e veja o que acontece, a url é indicada na barra porém o conteúdo não abre. Essa por exemplo: http://oprojetoweb.com.br/provas/security-condominios-programado/controle-de-acesso-topdata-w-access-tag-veicular-sem-parar-automoveis-condominio-sao-paulo-sorocaba-jundiai  abre normalmente.

Comment: Conseguir resolver, existia uma lista de palavras que quando são encontradas na url a página é bloqueada. No meu caso o que estava gerando o bloqueio era "net". Enfim, conseguir resolver, era questão de configuração mesmo.